# Android visibility changing animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

In the beginning I have clear layout with one image in the center ( http://cs621717.vk.me/v621717943/26b09/SDIeOAfMNwg.jpg).

After one second image should move to the top, and under it must be show another views (http://cs621717.vk.me/v621717943/26b13/zqdHf_yvRvY.jpg)

That's my initial layout-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/logo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="64dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@drawable/google_logo" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="48dip"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:gravity="center">

        <TextView
            android:id="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="2sp"
            android:text="@string/splash_text_1"
            android:textColor="@color/primary_text_color"
            android:textColorLink="@color/curious_blue"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/login_btn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignRight="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_alignStart="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_below="@android:id/text1"
            android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
            android:background="@color/curious_blue"
            android:text="@string/splash_login_btn_text_1"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You forgot to mention the error/non-required behavior?

Comment: When I change 'content' visibility to View.VISIBLE and 'container' gravity to (Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP) the image move to right top corner of screen, and later in center